# method missing in Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using AngularJS for Facebook (customized from [Ciul/angular-facebook](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook/blob/master/lib/angular-facebook.js)) and downloaded full debug version of [Facebook's Javascript SDK](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js) and stored it on my server as:

> facebooksdk.js

It works fine in every aspect that I can tell, but in my Chrome console, it shows the following error message:

```
Error: method missing
Error
    at Object.<anonymous> (/facebooksdk.js:1774:26)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (/facebooksdk.js:447:20)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (/facebooksdk.js:443:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (/facebooksdk.js:443:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (/facebooksdk.js:443:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (/facebooksdk.js:443:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (/facebooksdk.js:443:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (/facebooksdk.js:443:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (/facebooksdk.js:443:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (/facebooksdk.js:443:46) angular.js:5601
(anonymous function) angular.js:5601
(anonymous function) angular.js:4698
wrappedCallback angular.js:6695
(anonymous function) angular.js:6730
Scope.$eval angular.js:7905
Scope.$digest angular.js:7770
Scope.$apply angular.js:7991
(anonymous function) facebook.js:176
Scope.$broadcast angular.js:8155
$window.fbAsyncInit facebook.js:273
func.__wrapper facebooksdk.js:5608
(anonymous function)
```

facebooksdk.js:1774 is this:

```
__d("ManagedError",[],function(global,require,requireDynamic,requireLazy,module,exports) {
function ManagedError(message, innerError) {
  Error.prototype.constructor.call(this, message);
  this.message = message;
  this.innerError = innerError;
}
ManagedError.prototype = new Error();  //////// <---------- line 1774
ManagedError.prototype.constructor = ManagedError;

module.exports = ManagedError;


});
```

facebooksdk.js:447 is this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  switch(deps[i]) {
    case 'module'        : dep = module; break;
    case 'exports'       : dep = module.exports; break;
    case 'global'        : dep = global; break;
    case 'require'       : dep = require; break;
    case 'requireDynamic': dep = require; break;
    case 'requireLazy'   : dep = null; break;
    default              : dep = require.call(null, deps[i]);  ///// <---- line 443
  }
  args.push(dep);
}
module.factory.apply(global, args);  //////// <-------- line 447
resolved[id] = module.exports;
return module.exports;
```

Can anyone suggest how to get rid of this "method missing" error.  Thanks!

Comment: Probably, you have included your scripts in a wrong order.

Comment: @Engineer Which scripts would be in the wrong order, and what order should they be in?  I'm using the code from https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook

Comment: Correct order should be `angular>facebook sdk>angular-facebook` . Also [angular-facebook](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook/blob/master/lib/angular-facebook.js) lib could be incompatible with your version of angular.js. Pls, check it too.

Comment: @Engineer The code from github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook injects the Facebook SDK, so I do not set the order.  Should I be changing the code in github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook ?  If so, how do I change the order of the Facebook SDK?  I'm using AngularJS 1.0.4.  https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook/blob/master/bower.json states "devDependencies": {"angular": "~1.0.8", "angular-mocks": "~1.0.8"}  Does this mean that

Comment: ... github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook needs AngularJS 1.0.8?  However, I installed github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook approximately 9 months ago, so I do not know what version of AngularJS it needed back then. Would you happen to know?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with `angular-facebook` lib. Try to do some research about the angular version they support.